# How to access adjacent elements from a current starting position?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix:

```
E = [ 3 6 3 7 2 ; 3 8 3 7 2; 1 9 5 4 1; 7 5 1 6 9; 10 8 4 3 10 ]
```

If I started at `E(3,3) = 5`, how do I access the adjacent numbers to the east (or west). For example, I wanted to access the 3 elements to the east of `E(3,3)`, which are 7, 4 and 6.

Comment: I am confused, In the third row you have `7 9 5 6 9 2`. Why are the elements 7,4,6 to the east (right?) of the third element in this row? If `r,c` are the row and columns of the element of interest, have you tried `E(r,1:c)` or `E(r,c:end)`?

Comment: @Irreducible sorry. I just realized I copied the wrong matrix, thank you. I've just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% define matrix and point
E = [ 3 6 3 7 2 ; 3 8 3 7 2; 1 9 5 4 1; 7 5 1 6 9; 10 8 4 3 10 ];
Raw=3;
Col=3;

% find the value of the point, 3 east values and 3 west values
Point=E(Raw,Col)
EastVal=E(max(1,Raw-1):min(size(E,1),Raw+1),Col+1)
WestVal=E(max(1,Raw-1):min(size(E,1),Raw+1),Col-1)
```

Produce:

```
Point =

     5


EastVal =

     7
     4
     6


WestVal =

     8
     9
     5
```

Comment: Good Question. (4,2) is not edge point, but (1,2) is. See edit. But- What do you want to be the output in the column edge, where there no west or east at all, for example point (4,1)- what west should get?